# How do I use a profiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Very often I hear: use a profiler and unit test. How do I do that? I would be glad if someone would provide either links to websites with tutorials or recommend a good book. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Unit Testing and profiling are fundamentally different issues, maybe worth two questions. Plus, you may want to add some platform/language tags to attract a crowd.

Comment: The VS 2010 profiler in the ultimate edition is freaking amazing btw.

Answer (score 1):

[Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) describes how to use a profiler with VS 2008 - it *should* be applicable to VS 2010 as well.

Regarding Unit Tests and Profilers:

- Unit Tests may be used to validate that your application code fulfills a set of known conditions. Or more simply, test cases are set up to run code and to return Test Passed or Test Failed based upon a set of "assert" statements you place in your test code.
- Profilers may be used to inspect running code, to identify the functions your code is executing, what resources it is using, etc. This is helpful for identifying application bottlenecks (for example, 90% of CPU cycles might be spent within a single function) and for measuring optimization improvements.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/profiler/archive/2009/06/10/write-faster-code-with-vs-2010-profiler.aspx) is the VS Profiler Team Blog.

RedGate have several profiling [tools for .NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet_tools_overview.htm) - they have lots of videos and content on how to use them.

[Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/performance/using-a-profiler-to-speed-application-performance/) is a good article from simple talk (Using a Profiler to Speed Application Performance).