# Problem with multiplication of signed chars

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Discussing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840529/multiplying-int64s/5840570#5840570) answer I find out that the code bellow prints `-1` and `1` in visual studio. Why? In my opinion it should print two `1`s despit overflow during multiplication.

```
signed char c1 = numeric_limits<signed char>::min();
signed char c2 = -1;
cout << c1 * c2 / c1 << endl;
signed char result = c1 * c2;
cout << result / c1 << endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c1` might have a value like `-128`, say. In the multiplication, integer promotions will cause both `c1` and `c2` to be converted to type `int` before the operation is performed.

`c1 * c2` is then going to be a `int` with value `128` so `c1 * c2 / c1` is going to be an `int` with value `-1`.

`-1` for the first output looks correct to me.

For the second version, typically the assignment of the result of `c1 * c2` won't fit into a `signed char` and will convert to an implementation-defined result, perhaps `-128` instead of `128`.

Comment: But why `c1 * c2` is going to be an `int`? Is this standart?

Comment: @Mihran because of integer promotion

Comment: @MihranHovespyan: Integral promotions apply to both operands of `*` so both `signed char` will be promoted to `int` before the multiplication is performed.

Comment: As weird as it may look, you can verify this with a simple test program: `void foo(int) { std::cout << "int"; } void foo(char) { std::cout << "char"; } int main() { char a=1, b=2; foo(a*b); }`, the output of which will be "int" (the same goes for other arithmetic operations)

Answer (score 2):

Integer overflow is considered UB. This means that the compiler will consider `(c1 * c2 / c1)` to be completely equivalent to `c2`.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3948479/395626) for additional info.

Comment: `c1 * c2` probably doesn't involve any _signed_ integer overflow unless the platform has identically sized `char` and `int`.

Comment: @Charles: which it doesn't (it's Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

`c1 * c2` is an `int` multiplication (5/9 in the standard). We know that CHAR_BIT is 8 on MSVC and that it uses two's complement representation for signed types, so we know the value: -128 * -1 is 128.

128 / -128 is -1, so that's the first result sorted.

Assigning `-CHAR_MIN` to a `signed char` has implementation-defined results (4.7/3), but we know in MSVC the result is -128. Then -128 / -1 is 1, so that's the second result sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The first case, making upscaling to an int explicit:

```
cout << ((int)c1 * c2 / c1 << endl;
```

the second case, assigning to an intermediate variable is equivalent to

```
cout << ((signed char)((int)c1 * c2)) / c1 << endl;
```

(Implicit casts to int done by the compiler made explicit.)

With two's complement, multiplying the largest negative value of a type by -1 leaves the value unchanged if it is restricted to the same number of bits. So, the second example, c1*c2 == c1. Even though the multiplication is done as an int, it is cast back to the width of a char.

In the first example, the entire calaulation is done as an int, so the operation has more bits to work with, and so the truncation doesn't occur. Here, c1*c2 == (c1*-1) == -c1. Hence the different result.

Comment: The promotion to `int` is redundant, the implementation does this anyway. In this case, in `(signed char)((int)c1 * c2)` there is no overflow of an arithmetic operation, there's an explicit conversion from one integer type to another. This would be implementation-defined, not underfined behavior.